# Adding bootstrap fade manually?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, fade

I'm using bootstrap 3. I'm manually adding the classes for the fade like bootstrap has:

```
jQuery("#element").addClass('in active');
```

It seems these are 2 classes used by Bootstrap to cause a fade in effect. The in adds opacity, and the active adds `display: block;`

When I add them in manually with `jQuery .addClass()`, I only get the display block (without the fade in).

Is there a proper way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fade in and out a Bootstrap 3 modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23791787/fade-in-and-out-a-bootstrap-3-modal)

Comment: `jQuery('...').hide(400)`? Bootstrap class `.fade` as mentioned?

Comment: @KiranShahi Nope not a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

use fade in instead because it has the definition like this:

```
.fade.in {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: My elements already have a fade class, so I'm manually adding the "in" class. So my end result has class="fade in active"

Comment: try to put  it and and see if it works in your jquery method